# Talend - SUBJOB_OK trigger not available in custom component

Tags: talend

I'm creating a custom component, and I'd like this component triggers on SUBJOB_OK, but despite I've added the connectors to the Component Descriptor XML file (in fact, I've copied them from `tMySQLConnection`), the option does not appear in the componente menu:

```
  <CONNECTORS> 
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="FLOW" MAX_INPUT="0" MAX_OUTPUT="0"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="ITERATE" MAX_OUTPUT="0" MAX_INPUT="1"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="SUBJOB_OK" MAX_INPUT="1"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="SUBJOB_ERROR" MAX_INPUT="1"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="COMPONENT_OK"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="COMPONENT_ERROR"/>
    <CONNECTOR CTYPE="RUN_IF"/>
  </CONNECTORS>
```

These are the only triggers I'm able to see:

[image]

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Found [here](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=37975): `I have just forget to set Startable on true!`.

Comment: Perfect, that was the point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as @tobi6 suggested, the component was not "startable" (this is a property to be set in the Component Descriptor XML file).